# Cygnal Integrated Products serial port on Linux

Tags: linux, tty, usbserial

I have an infrared thermometer which operates on a virtual serial port over USB, which I am trying to use on Debian Linux.  Unfortunately, the system does not enumerate a `/dev/ttyUSB` device.

Here is the `dmesg` for the device:

```
usb 5-1: new full-speed USB device number 3 using uhci_hcd
usb 5-1: New USB device found, idVendor=10c4, idProduct=834b
usb 5-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
usb 5-1: Product: Infrared Online Sensor Adapter
usb 5-1: Manufacturer: Silicon Labs
usb 5-1: SerialNumber: CT00092755
```

And here is the `lsusb -v`:

```
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 10c4:834b Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc.
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         0
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x10c4 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc.
  idProduct          0x834b
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1
  iProduct                2
  iSerial                 3
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      0
      bInterfaceProtocol      0
      iInterface              2
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
```

How can I get this working, so I can connect to it with the serial port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out this devices uses a standard Silicon Labs CP2102 interface chip, which the device manufacturer loaded with a custom `idProduct` number.  While the chip is 100% compatible with the `cp210x.ko` driver, the `idProduct` is not recognized by the system, and does not associate the driver with it.

At this point, there are several possible solutions:

- Manually direct the system to use the `cp210x.ko` driver with this `idProduct`.
- Add the `idProduct` to the [open source driver](http://www.silabs.com/products/mcu/Pages/USBtoUARTBridgeVCPDrivers.aspx#linux), compile, and install it.  Then try to push the changes into standard Linux repositories.
- Replace the customized chip with generic one.
- Rewrite the `idProduct` on the chip.

I chose to rewrite the `idProduct`.  Silicon Labs has a [free utility](http://www.silabs.com/products/Interface/Pages/interface-application-notes.aspx) to do just this.  I set the `idProduct=EA60`, which is the default for this chip.  The device is now recognized by the standard built-in driver, and works perfectly.

Comment: The "free utility" is now [Direct Access Drivers](https://www.silabs.com/products/development-tools/software/direct-access-drivers). After you install it, look in the folders for `CP21xxCustomizationUtility.exe`